# Finding x for which this series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So i have this defined:
$ a_{2n-1}=(-1)^{2n+1} , a_{2n}=2 $

And i have to find all $ x\in \mathbb{R}  \backslash{(-2)}$
That this series is convergent:

$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1} }{(x+2)^n} ) 
$

And for those x-s, calculate sum.

So my first thought was to go for leibnitz criteria, but because there are x-s, that was a long shot, we were thought that all those criteria go out as soon you have "for what x this series..." and we bave to first look at absolute convergence. But i am not sure,so any help would be appreciate.
And for more info: i can only use absolute convergence,and criteris: sandwich rule for series, root criteria, raabe and delambert criteria(not sure about the name though).
So that's all i have.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Necessary condition for convergence: the terms must tend to $0$. When is that the case here?

Comment: I know that, but how do i check it?

Comment: Which part of the term of the series determines its size?

Comment: I'm not used to doing it english, so i don't really get what you are saying. I know that limit of sequence that makes up this series should be $0$ but i think that it does something to do with x that have absolite value lower than 1. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, something to do with $x$ should have absolute value less than $1$. Look at the terms of the series to see which part needs to have an absolute value less than $1$.

Comment: Those $a_{n}$ are not really relevant, i just have to look for x-es for which this series absolutelly converges and then look what happens with others,but still i have tried  it with root criteria and got a limit bigger than 1 so i guess i have to use another one....maybe raabe?

Comment: I think that $x+2$ should be lower than 1 as absolute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is strightforward. Let's rewrite sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (-1)^{n+1} x \left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^n,$$
and denote $t=x/(x+2)$. We need explore series
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (-1)^{n+1}t^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n t^n.$$

For $n=2m-1$, we have $a_{2m-1}=-1$, $b_n=-1$.

For $n=2m$, we have $a_{2m}=2$, $b_n=-2$.

Hence
$$-S = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (t^{2m-1}+2t^{2m}).$$
We need $|t| < 1$ for convergence. For $t<0$, we may to use Leibnitz criteria. For $t>0$, all summand are positive, and it's a geometric progression:
$$-S = (t+t^3 +\ldots) + 2(t^2+t^4+\ldots)=\frac{t}{1-t^2}+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}.$$
Now we can see that for $t<0$
$$-S = -(t+t^3 +\ldots) + 2(t^2+t^4+\ldots)=-\frac{t}{1-t^2}+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2},$$
or
$$-S = \frac{t}{1-t^2}\frac{|t|}{t}+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2} = \frac{|t|}{1-t^2}+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}$$
It's not hard to see that in $t=\pm1$ series diverges.

So, it $|x/(x+2)| < 1$, your series is
$$-\frac{x}{1-t^2}(2t^2+|t|)=\frac{x}{\frac{x^2}{(x+2)^2}-1}\left(\frac{2x^2}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{|x|}{|x+2|}\right)=\\=
\frac{x}{x^2-(x+2)^2}\left(2x^2 + |x(x+2)|\right)=
-\frac14\frac{x}{x+1}\left(2x^2 + |x(x+2)|\right)$$

Comment: What about that x outside fraction?

Comment: @user246608, what do you mean?

Comment: When u rewrote the sum, there you put one x outside the fraction to make it with power n,but when u used $t=x/(x+2)$ then you forgot about that x?

Comment: @user246608, multiplication by $x$ doesn't change convergence of series, therefore I forgot about $x$ before answer.

Comment: Oh okay,thankyou for your time.